# How to send value in DatePicker to a controller

Tags: telerik-mvc

I have DatePicker in mvc2 form and want to send it value to a controller. However there is no databinding for DatePicker, and I can not bind a function in databinding.select. How to send its value to a controller after clicking submit button? Thanks. The code is,

```
Html.Telerik().DatePicker()
.Name("DatePicker")
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-size:8pt;width:100px" })
.ShowButton(true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get value from telerik datepicker with:

```
$('#DatePicker').data("tDateTimePicker").value();
```

Also datepicker have an input with id which value equal your datepicker control name so you should use it in controller method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<%= Html.Telerik( ).DatePickerFor( model => model.YourDateProperty )`

From your question, I infer that you've already wrapped this datepicker in a form, which is good.  Now just collect the value in the [Post] method in the controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeActionMethod (YourViewModel model)
{
   model.YourDateProperty//This will be the value from the datepicker
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it three way.

1) pass your Model to your controller
2) use FormCollection to get value of DatePicker
3) [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Index(string dttCompletion) // should be same as your datepicker name.
   {

}